# Casting pointer to pointer **p (malloc(sizeof(int*))) to a pointer *p

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int*));//line 1
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("%d",*n);
}
```

I am not sure what is happening here.
Does line 1 (in the snippet above) mean n now simply is a pointer to an int?
And we have started using the memory allocated for a pointer as variable itself?
Is the pointer to pointer cast to pointer to int?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
int *n = malloc(sizeof(int*));//line 1
```

you allocated memory of the size equal to `sizeof( int * )` and its address is assigned to the pointer `n` having the type `int *`.

So using this pointer to access the memory it is interpreted as a memory storing an object of the type `int`

```
scanf("%d",n);
printf("%d",*n);
```

Actually the kind of the argument expression used to specify the size of the allocated memory is not very important. For example you could just write

```
int *n = malloc( 8 );//line 1
```

Comment: So int \*n = malloc(sizeof(int*)); is behaving the same way as int *n = malloc(sizeof(int)) ?

Comment: @Vaibhav You are right. The only difference is the value of the expressions sizeof( int ) and sizeof ( int * ). For example sizeof( int * ) can be equal to 8 while sizeof( int ) can be equal to 4.  But in any case an extent of memory equal to 8 can store an object of the type int.

Comment: so does that mean int \*\*n=malloc(sizeof(double)); will work as intended? (n points to a location which further points to memory location of an int)? @Vlad

Comment: @Vaibhav If the value of the expression sizeof( double )  is not less than the value of the expression sizeof( int * ) then there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` knows nothing about types, it only cares about the size.

The correct incantations are

```
T *t = malloc(sizeof(*t)); // or
T *t = malloc(sizeof(T));
```

If you pass any other expression to `malloc` and it by sheer coincidence happens to have the correct value, you get lucky and nothing bad happens. But this is confusing. Do not confuse the readers of your code.

If the value passed to `malloc` is greater than the correct one, you just waste memory. If it is less, you risk Undefined Behaviour.

It is implementation defined whether `sizeof(int)` is the same as, larger than, or smaller than `sizeof(int*)` so just don't do that.

Comment: Recommend not using "()" with `sizeof` unless necessary, and that your first example is better as it is less prone to careless introduction of bugs because datatype appears only once in the statement.